# UITableView Header rendering issues with UITableView Animations

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm using **`tableView:willDisplayHeaderView:forSection:`** to customize my header views. And it seems to work under normal user scrolling just perfectly. But if the `UITableView` is scrolled via an animation (ie. a Deleted row) the method is not called, even though the header comes into view as a result of that animation.

**Please note this is NOT `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` :)**

The code is as follows:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayHeaderView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    //Type Cast the view to UITableViewHeaderFooterView
    UITableViewHeaderFooterView *header = (UITableViewHeaderFooterView *)view;

    //Change tintColor property of header to black
    header.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    //See if there is an existing custom subview in the header
    CustomHeaderView* headerContentView = (CustomHeaderView*)[header viewWithTag:1007];

    //If it doesn't exist make it.
    if(headerContentView == nil){ 
        headerContentView = [[CustomHeaderView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, view.frame.size.width, 40.0f)];
        headerContentView.tag = 1007;

        if(section==0){
            headerContentView.label.text =  @"Current Members";
        }
        if(section==1){
            headerContentView.label.text =  @"Others Nearby";
        }            

        [header.contentView addSubview:headerContentView];
    }        
}
```

Okay. This does what I'd expect when I'm scrolling through the table. It makes the headers black, adds the custom view, and makes the text in those custom views whatever I specify.

However, it doesn't seem to be calling `tableView:willDisplayHeaderView:forSection:` if I perform an animation on the `UITableView`, (after a delete for instance) and as a result of the animation the header comes in without rendering properly at all (blank white):

```
- (void)cellDidSelectDelete:(UITableViewCell *)cell {

    [self.tableView beginUpdates];    
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

    [self.tableModel removeItemForUser:cell.userID];
    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    [self.tableView endUpdates];        
}
```

The header that is revealed by the animation comes in white (not black as specified), and the `tableView:willDisplayHeaderView:forSection:` method is not even called (I've tried logging it).

Would any one have any idea what the heck is happening here? Is it a bug?

Thanks so much for any leads!